# Touchpad not working on toshiba p50

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, toshiba-satellite

I have a toshiba P50 notebook and touchpad stopped working in my Xubuntu 15.10. I upgraded to 16.04, but still not working. Its recognized though:

```
  xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any ideas how to get it work again? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit `50-synaptics.conf` file :

```
 nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option "TapButton1" "1"
```

Like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
```

Save , exit and reboot

Comment: sorry, it didn't work